# searching for a phrase in Mongodb: weird behaviour

Tags: mongodb, text-search

i have the following collection:

```
books> db.books.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab85b0056b5357b5e23e6b"),
    fields: 'hello good morning'
  },
  { _id: ObjectId("61ab85b5056b5357b5e23e6c"), fields: 'good morning' },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab8679056b5357b5e23e6d"),
    fields: 'hello good morning guys'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab8684056b5357b5e23e6e"),
    fields: 'good morning guys'
  }
]
```

Then, i run this query:

```
db.books.find({$text : {$search : "\"good morning\" hello"}})
```

and i get:

```
[
  { _id: ObjectId("61ab85b5056b5357b5e23e6c"), fields: 'good morning' },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab8684056b5357b5e23e6e"),
    fields: 'good morning guys'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab85b0056b5357b5e23e6b"),
    fields: 'hello good morning'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61ab8679056b5357b5e23e6d"),
    fields: 'hello good morning guys'
  }
]
```

Can you help me to understand the output? The first result doesn't make much sense to me (document _id : ...23e6c), as it doesn't contain the "hello" string.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882368/mongodb-text-search-exact-phrase) the first answer to this question. Does it mean that, in my case, mongodb is searching for

```
(good morning) AND (good OR morning OR hello)
```

It would explain my question, but i can't find the exact reference to this in the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms):

> A string of terms that MongoDB parses and uses to query the text index. MongoDB performs a logical OR search of the terms unless specified as a phrase. See Behavior for more information on the field.

This is just the behavior a text index allows, What you can do it mark every single expression as a "phrase", like so:

```
{$text : {$search : "\"good morning\" \"hello\""}}
```

This will enforce `$and` logic.

Comment: In the same page of the documentation, i also read that "If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase.". Do i correctly understand that, by including a phrase in the search string, mongodb will ignore any additional individual term? It would also explain my output.

Comment: Yep, you understood it correctly. i edited my answer to reflect that as a better solution.